# Why if a polynomial is divided by x-1 and gives the remainder 3 then p (1) = 3?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why if a polynomial is divided by $x-1$ and gives the $remainder=3$ then $p(1) = 3$? Does it have to do with ruffini? Could you describe the steps that lead me to affirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Call $P$ your polynomial. By definition of division, $P=Q*(x-1)+3.$ for $Q$ a polynomial.
 Replace at $x=1.$

Answer (score 0):

$$P(x)=(x-a)\times Q(x)+R$$

$$P(a)=(a-a)\times Q(a)+R=R$$

here $a=1, R=3$

Answer (score 0):

This involves the direct application of the *remainder theorem*. The remainder theorem is a generalisation of the factor theorem. Recall that the factor theorem states

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial function. If $(x-a)$ is a factor of $P(x)$, then $P(a)=0 \, .$

It is easy to see why this theorem is true. Let $Q(x)$ be the  the quotient of $P(x)$ and $(x-a)$. Then we can write
$$
P(x) = Q(x)(x-a)
$$
This means that $P(a)=Q(a)(a-a)=0 \, .$ The remainder theorem is similar. Let's say we divide $P(x)$ by $(x-a)$, but this time we are left with the remainder $r$, meaning that
$$
P(x)=Q(x)(x-a)+r
$$
We can see that $P(a)=r$. Thus we can state the remainder theorem:

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial function. If dividing $P(x)$ by $(x-a)$ leaves a remainder of $r$, then $P(a)=r$

To apply this to the problem at hand, set $a=1$ and $r=3$.

Answer (score 0):

What does $P(x)$ having remainder $3$ after being divided by $3$ mean?

It means that there is a polynomial $\frac {P(x)}{x-1} = Q(x) + \frac 3{x-1}$ or in other words that $P(x) = Q(x)(x-1) + 3$.

So $P(1) = Q(1)(1-1) + 3 = Q(1)\cdot 0 + 3 = 0 + 3 =3$.

That's all.

======

If you *really* want details.  Suppose $P(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ..... + a_1x + a_0$ is an $n$th degree polynomial and $a_k$ are all rational numbers.

Now if $T(x) = b_{n-1}x^{n-1} + b_{n-2}x^{n-1} + .... + b_1x + b_0$ is some $n-1$ degree polynomial where $b_k$ are all rational numbers.

Then $T(x)(x-1) = b_{n-1}x^n + (b_{n-2}-b_{n-1})x^{n-1} + ......+ (b_1-b_2)x^2 + (b_0-b_1)x -b_0$ is an $n$ degree polynomial.

Now that means if we set $b_{n-1} = a_n; b_{n-2} =a_{n-1}+b_{n-1};....b_{k-1}= a_k+b_k$ down to $b_0=a_1 +b_1$ and then if we let $R=a_0 + b_0$, we get a unique $n-1$ degree polynomial, $Q(x)$ and a unique constant $R$, where$P(x) = Q(x)(x-1) + R$.

It is pretty easy to see this is the *only* such polynomial.  We *must* have $b_{n-1} = a_n$ and that means $b_{n-2}$ *must* equal $a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$ and so on.

Note: It will *always* be the case that $P(1) = Q(1)(1-1) + R = R$.

So if we are told $R=3$, that's it.  $P(1) = 3$.